# How can I resize a Fabric.js canvas and all the content inside?

Tags: fabricjs

Hello I'm trying to resize a Fabric.js canvas element and proportionally the content inside it. I just increase the width and height of canvas area, but the content like image, text, etc. remain in its original size.
How can i achieve this behavior.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

Use below function to resize canvas proportionally along with all the elements/objects. You can pass any width/size `GetCanvasAtResoution(279);` Hope this helps.

```
    function GetCanvasAtResoution(newWidth)
    {
        if (canvas.width != newWidth) {
            var scaleMultiplier = newWidth / canvas.width;
            var objects = canvas.getObjects();
            for (var i in objects) {
                objects[i].scaleX = objects[i].scaleX * scaleMultiplier;
                objects[i].scaleY = objects[i].scaleY * scaleMultiplier;
                objects[i].left = objects[i].left * scaleMultiplier;
                objects[i].top = objects[i].top * scaleMultiplier;
                objects[i].setCoords();
            }
            var obj = canvas.backgroundImage;
            if(obj){
                obj.scaleX = obj.scaleX * scaleMultiplier;
                obj.scaleY = obj.scaleY * scaleMultiplier;
            }

            canvas.discardActiveObject();
            canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * scaleMultiplier);
            canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * scaleMultiplier);
            canvas.renderAll();
            canvas.calcOffset();
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, i tried the function but only resize the canvas area not the objects inside. I call the function as you posted GetCanvasAtResoution(width);

Comment: @Álvaro I have created a jsfiddle to show how this function works to resize a canvas along with background image and text object present inside it - https://jsfiddle.net/zsk7785t/

Comment: Hi @Ranjana thank you very much, not it is working, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Ranjana you just saved me and by pair programmer hours of work. Thank you!

Comment: It was very useful! I spent couple of hours and this one finally worked :)

Comment: You saved me. I tried multiple solutions but had no luck. This on worked well.

Comment: You should add the jsfiddle to the answer. It is very useful. Thank you